# CMP0002 error when compiling different subproject with same target

Tags: cmake, target

I've many sub-folders

```
home
|
|-library1
|-library2
|
|-libraryn
```

Every subfolder contains a complete library that can compile by itself (every library has a different mantainer). Until now it works correctly and I compile them using a script.

Now I need to create another library, that depends on existing one. In order to do so, I've created a `CMakeLists.txt` under home folder, using `add_subdirectory` command that allows me to compile all libraries.

I've something like

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

add_subdirectory(library1)
add_subdirectory(library2)
...
add_subdirectory(libraryn)
```

When I try to execute `cmake` I obtain following error for various libraries:

```
CMake Error at libraryY/CMakeLists.txt:63 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "doc" because another target with
  the same name already exists.  The existing target is a custom target
  created in source directory
  "/path/to/libraryX".  See
  documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.
```

This happens because in every library we create a doc target in order to compile the Doxygen documentation of the library itself. It works fine when libraryes are compiled one by one, but with the master `CMakeLists.txt` it seems that I cannot do it.

```
# Create doc target for doxygen documentation compilation.
find_package (Doxygen)
if (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
  set (Doxygen_Dir ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/export/${Library_Version}/doc)
  # Copy images folder
  file (GLOB IMAGES_SRC "images/*")
  file (COPY ${IMAGES_SRC} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/images)
  configure_file (${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile @ONLY)
  add_custom_target (doc
    ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    COMMENT "Generating doxygen documentation" VERBATIM
  )
else (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
  message (STATUS "Doxygen must be installed in order to compile doc")
endif (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
```

Is there a way to compile these project at once without modify this target?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to modify anything so you can build all this projects as subprojects, then you can use [ExternalProject_Add](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html) to build and install dependencies.

#### option

Alternatively you can use [option](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/option.html) command to exclude `doc` target from build:

```
# Foo/CMakeLists.txt
option(FOO_BUILD_DOCS "Build doc target for Foo project" OFF)
# ...
if(DOXYGEN_FOUND AND FOO_BUILD_DOCS)
  add_custom_target(doc ...)
endif()

# Boo/CMakeLists.txt
option(BOO_BUILD_DOCS "Build doc target for Boo project" OFF)
# ...
if(DOXYGEN_FOUND AND BOO_BUILD_DOCS)
  add_custom_target(doc ...)
endif()
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't use `ExternalProject_Add` because we are using CMake version 2.8.7. I've tried the second method and it works, but doc target is not created. And if I declare both options to ON with -D command line argument I've the same error. It helps, but I must compile documentation in a separate step. I don't blame your solution, I like it! I'm saying it only if other people have my same problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nevermind.. I've just discovered that ExternalProject is a separate module and that can be used also with this CMake version. Thanks again.

Comment: `but doc target is not created.` it depends on your needs. If you want doc target to be created by default you need to set `option(... ON)`. `I've the same error. It helps, but I must compile documentation in a separate step.` AFAIK there is no way out of that, you can't create two targets with the same name in one project. Note that you can rename it, e.g. foo_doc, boo_doc. Or more of that, you can create targets name by condition, for example if target `doc` is already exists, pick target name `foo_doc`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (NOT (TARGET DOCUMENTATION))
    add_custom_target(DOCUMENTATION COMMENT "workaround for multi-dependencies project")
    add_dependencies(DOCUMENTATION DOCUMENTATION_${PROJECT_NAME})
endif()
```

I have tested this and used it in real life.
It works for multiple projects.

Comment: This could have been useful if all projects had a different target name for documentation. The problem would not occur in that case though.

Comment: I think you need to read again the code :-)
It basically hides the `DOCUMENTATION` target under a custom target called `DOCUMENTATION_${PROJECT_NAME}`

Comment: Well, I like the idea here. Create target `DOCUMENTATION` for Doxygen targets just like `ALL_BUILD`. But as I said, it requires the Doxygen targets of the subfolders to have separate names. This is not a solution to subfolders' having same name target problem but rather a best practice recommendation.