# CMake: another target with same name exists in one of the linked library

Tags: c, cmake

Complelety new to CMake.
I am getting following error : `add_library cannot create target "hello-pack" because another target with the same name already exists.`

My directory structure are as such :

[image: Directory structure]

my app uses two libs : **hello-pack** and **hello-world-pack**.

**hello-world-pack** depends upon **hello-pack** too to deliver its functionality.

myapp2 CMakeLists.txt file content is as such :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

project("myapp2" C)

add_subdirectory("hello-pack")
add_subdirectory("hello-world-pack")

add_executable("${PROJECT_NAME}" myapp2.c)
target_include_directories("${PROJECT_NAME}" 
    PRIVATE "hello-pack/include" 
    PRIVATE "hello-world-pack/include")
target_link_libraries("${PROJECT_NAME}" "hello-pack" "hello-world-pack")
target_link_directories("${PROJECT_NAME}" 
PRIVATE "hello-pack"
PRIVATE "hello-world-pack")
```

Here is the git repo for this code:
https://github.com/anuragvohraec/myapp2.git

hello-pack prints out: `hello!`

[image: hello-pack code]

and hello world prints out: `hello! world!`

[image]

I wanted to simulate a situation where in my main app and a dependent library uses a common package for building.

Comment: You already add the target `hello-pack` via the call to `add_subdirectory("hello-pack")` in your top-level CMake. There is no need to define this target again in the `hello-world-pack` directory, unless this is a different set of code. Why does this code seem to be duplicated in two places?

Comment: @squareskittles Lets assume `hello-world-pack` is thri party library which too depends upon `hello-pack`. I know the reason for the error, but I am looking for the solution. If in a real project if two or more libraires have common depedencies, hw to get it resolved in CMake, is what I am looking for.

Comment: This is downside of `add_subdirectory` approach for include 3d-party project: CMake files for that project may conflict with CMake files of the main project. In general, you cannot fix the problem without modifying CMake files. Alternative approaches - pre-building 3d-party project (and possible using of [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/find_package.html) after that) or including the subproject via [ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/module/ExternalProject.html) - don't suffer from this problem.

Comment: There are several questions on Stack Overflow about this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998342/cmp0002-error-when-compiling-different-subproject-with-same-target, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978414/how-to-handle-a-transitive-dependency-conflict-using-git-submodules-and-cmake, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691109/in-cmake-how-to-create-targets-with-identical-names.